# xx is subject to hotel’s confirmation

Tags: expressions

Should I say "xx is subject to hotel's confirmation" or "xx is subject to hotel confirmation"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either "subject to the hotel's confirmation," indicating this particular hotel or "subject to hotel confirmation," indicating the general type of confirmation.

English uses nouns as adjectives in noun-noun phrases all the time, e.g., office worker, meeting summary, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Hotel's confirmation. "Hotel confirmation" sounds like a made up noun.

Comment: Nouns can be used as adjectives in English. "Hotel confirmation" is just a noun phrase where _hotel_ modifies _confirmation_. What kind of confirmation? The kind from, or about, or related to a hotel.